# Excited states of boron

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, quantum-spin, spectroscopy

I came across this diagram when I was looking for the order of excitations of boron atom (Phys. Rev. A 83, 022505):

[image]

However, when I was trying to work out the spectroscopic notation of first excited configuration of boron ($1s^2 2s^1 2p^2$), I obtained the following states, from lowest to highest energy: $^4P,^2D,^2P,^2S$. It seems like $^2S,^2P$ obtained from the configuration ($1s^2 2s^1 2p^2$) were ignored in this paper. Does anyone know what happened here?

[Correlated-Gaussian calculations of the ground and low-lying excited states of the boron atom](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.83.022505)